# Shell Command Starting with ">"

Tags: bash, shell

I recently came across a shell command that looked like this: "> outfile < infile cat", which appears to be functionally equivalent to "cat infile > outfile". For that matter, the general form seems to be "> outfile < infile command arg1 ... argN" becomes "command arg1 ... argN infile > outfile".

Anyway, I was wondering if anyone could elaborate on how the leading ">" achieves this effect, and if there are any practical uses for it.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Its a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ["Bash Reference Manual"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirection) says the following about the redirection operators:

> The following redirection operators may precede or appear anywhere within a simple command or may follow a command.

So the following commands are all equivalent:

```
ls -al > listing.txt
> listing.txt ls -al
ls > listing.txt -al
```

Though I'd guess that the first is most common form.

Note that the relative *order* of redirections is significant, so if you're redirecting one file descriptor to another, for example, the following would be different:

```
ls > listing.txt 2>&1   # both stdout and stderr go in to listing.txt

ls 2>&1 > listing.txt   # only stdout goes to listing.txt, because stderr was made
                        #    a copy of stdout before the redirection of stdout
```

Answer (score 4):

The ">" simply redirects the output of the command to the file given as the next argument. The typical use is to append this at the end of the command but it can be in any place. So:

`> outfile <command>` is equivalent to  `<command> > outfile`. Same holds true for the input redirection.

Please note that in the above examples `<command>` is not some weird syntax - it simply replaces arbitrary command.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use angle brackets around your mythical 'command' - it makes the example somewhat confusing.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yeap I thought of that but couldn't come up with better format.

Comment: `> OUTFILE COMMAND`, `> %outfile% %command%`, `> $outfile $command`

Comment: How about using a real example for easier reading: `dir="$(mktemp -d)"; > "$dir"/test.txt ls`

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent is not:

```
cat infile > outfile
```

Rather, it is

```
cat < infile > outfile
```

(just that in case of cat, `cat infile` is same as `cat <infile`)

Once you see it that way, the original command seems more straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

One note. It's because you can actually write this

```
< file command
```

it makes the Useless Use of Cat all the more inexcusable:

```
cat file | command
```

That is, even if for some reason you want the file to be syntactically to the left of the command, you still don't need `cat`!

Answer (score 0):

A leading greater than sign (>) is used to redirect output. By default it will redirect STDOUT. In this case, STDOUT is empty and thus a new and  empty file is created (similar effect to `touch output`).

You can also use this style of command to empty existing files, ie

```
    $ echo FOO >/tmp/foo
    $ ls -l /tmp/foo
    -rw-r--r--  1 flah  wheel  4 Apr 17 01:49 /tmp/foo
    $ > /tmp/foo
    $ ls -l /tmp/foo
    -rw-r--r--  1 flah  wheel  0 Apr 17 01:49 /tmp/foo
    $
```

For more info see the Redirection section of the bash man page.